# AWS Amplify customized Auth sign-in gets stock (pending) randomly on android, but works perfectly on ios and both simulators

Tags: android, react-native, expo, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am developing an App with expo and Amazon Amplify as backend. I am trying to make my customized authentication process. The app works perfectly fine with both Android and ios simulators, also when I test it on my phone, (by scanning the QR code) it works on ios perfectly fine, but for Android, I get the following message in the console. The funny thing is that last night it worked fine with my wife's 3a pixel and did not work with my phone (I also have a 3a pixel), and now it works fine with my phone and does not work with hers. I have upgraded the Amplify packages as explained [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/troubleshooting/upgrading/q/platform/js/#check-for-duplicate-versions), but it did not help.

```
Pending sign-in attempt already in progress
at node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:535:17 in AuthClass.prototype.signInWithPassword
at node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/lib-esm/Auth.js:421:22 in AuthClass.prototype.signIn
at screens/SignInScreen.tsx:47:24 in signInHandler
at http://10.129.23.79:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:156070:39 in signInHandler
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:697:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:634:6 in _receiveSignal
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:528:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
```

Comment: To give you an update on this problem, after a long time the signIn() worked and signed me in, but now the signOut() button is stuck, exactly the same way. It seems everything is extremely slow.

Comment: I have an assets folder in my app, that has some large images in it, and I require() them in the app, and resize them. Do you think this can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Looks like the SDKs might have gotten out of sync or corrupted. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app worked for my React Native app (cra). I'd maybe suggest clearing cache and cookies on web